# How can I round up my poll answers?

Tags: php, rounding

I would like to round up poll answers, but I can't get it working.

When I try `round_up` and `ceil`, I get `10x` percents (over 100%, most 101%).

Example values:

```
33.3333333333 
16.6666666667
50
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `round()`?

it should result in:

```
33
17
50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
round(33.3333333333, 2); //result: 33.33
round(16.6666666667, 2); //result: 16.67
round(50, 2); //result: 50
```

Comment: +1 but based on what he is using already, he just wants the integer part.

Comment: My foult, i was using "round up".
Thank you very much ;)